# Spring-data and Spring-security integration

Tags: spring, spring-security, integration, spring-data

The document said by introducing a bean of type SecurityEvaluationContextExtension then it will make available all the commons built-in security expressions like 'principal', 'hasRole', etc. The example shows a simple integration using 'principal' in the @Query

```
@Query("select m from Message m where m.to.id = ?#{ principal?.id }")
```

Now what if I want to select all the messages regardless what the 'm.to.id' is if the principal hasRole 'ADMIN' or something like that. I've tried these but only to encounter errors from spring-data parsing the query

```
@Query("select m from Message m where m.to.id = ?#{ principal?.id } or hasRole('ADMIN')")

@Query("select m from Message m where m.to.id = ?#{ principal?.id } or 'true' = ?#{ hasRole('ADMIN') }")

@Query("select m from Message m where m.to.id = ?#{ principal?.id } or 1 = ?#{ hasRole('ADMIN') }")
```

Can we accomplish something like that? Basically if the user is a regular user then only give them their own messages, but the admin users can get all the messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a similar use case in our [spring-data-examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/security/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/security/SecureBusinessObjectRepository.java):

```
@Query("select o from BusinessObject o where o.owner.emailAddress like ?#{hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ? '%' : principal.emailAddress}")
List<BusinessObject> findBusinessObjectsForCurrentUser();
```

In your case you could try something like that (in the context of the mentioned spring-data-examples project)

The repository method:

```
@Query("select o from BusinessObject o where o.owner.id = ?#{principal.id} or 1=?#{hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ? 1 : 0}")
List<BusinessObject> findBusinessObjectsForCurrentUserById();
```

Some tests to verify:

```
@Test
public void findBusinessObjectsForCurrentUserByIdShouldReturnOnlyBusinessObjectsWhereCurrentUserIsOwner(){

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(tom,"x"));

    List<BusinessObject> businessObjects = secureBusinessObjectRepository.findBusinessObjectsForCurrentUserById();

    assertThat(businessObjects,hasSize(1));
    assertThat(businessObjects,contains(object3));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(olli,"x"));

    businessObjects = secureBusinessObjectRepository.findBusinessObjectsForCurrentUserById();

    assertThat(businessObjects,hasSize(2));
    assertThat(businessObjects,contains(object1,object2));
}


@Test
public void findBusinessObjectsForCurrentUserByIdShouldReturnAllObjectsForAdmin(){

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(admin,"x", Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))));

    List<BusinessObject> businessObjects = secureBusinessObjectRepository.findBusinessObjectsForCurrentUserById();

    assertThat(businessObjects,hasSize(3));
    assertThat(businessObjects,contains(object1,object2, object3));
}
```